# Using UNIQUE IDENTIFIERS as PRIMARY KEY in a High-Availability, Active-Active Environment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our company is moving our databases to a **High-Availability, Active-Active** (HA/AA) environment. The middle-ware tool we chose makes it VERY painful to migrate Identity columns between live instances. As such, I and other folks want to move to using `uniqueidentifiers` (i.e. Guid's) for primary keys for all new tables.

CONSIDERATIONS:

- Some tables will be quite shallow
- Other tables will grow extremely large (over time)
- Many legacy tables already contain millions of records

THE PROPOSED SOLUTION:

Use sequential `uniqueidentifier` as primary key for tables

THE CONCERN:

The effect of having millions of records using a `uniqueidentifier` as primary key for tables.

**QUESTION:** In general, how well have `uniqueidentifier` performed for you in these situations?

**UPDATE:**

By primary key I mean surrogate.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  GUIDs are not sequential unique identifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GUID` may seem to be a natural choice for your primary key - and if you really must, you could probably argue to use it for the PRIMARY KEY of the table. What I'd strongly recommend **not to do** is use the `GUID` column as the **clustering key**, which SQL Server does by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.

You really need to keep two issues apart:

1. the **primary key** is a logical construct - one of the candidate keys that uniquely and reliably identifies every row in your table. This can be anything, really - an `INT`, a `GUID`, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.
2. the **clustering key** (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - `INT` or `BIGINT` as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seen massive performance gains when breaking up the previous GUID-based primary / clustered key into two separate keys - the primary (logical) key on the `GUID`, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the *Queen of Indexing* - and others have stated a great many times - a `GUID` as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the `GUID` - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an `INT` with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a `GUID` as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using `INT` vs. `GUID` as primary and clustering key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Comment: So, using an IDENTITY as a clustering key isnt possible due to the choice in middle -ware.  Thoughts?

Comment: make it unique? Adding rows could be done through procs or triggers (always prefer procs) to enforce uniqueness

Comment: @PrisonerZERO `CLUSTERED` and `PRIMARY KEY` is not the same thing. See the first link in answer above: _primary AND/OR clustered_. **FK**s are referencing **PK**.

Answer (score 1):

Read about the GUIDs vs INT debate here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate/

Seq GUID is not that worse than INT/BIGINT as many folks think about. It has advantages over BIGINT when in question is MERGE-ing of data, as the question is more about. 
Seq GUID has a stable fragmentation too, and looses a bit on performance against BIGINT.

*Note*: Identnity data types have some issues when unexpected switching between the nodes occurs.
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2014/06/17/lost-identity.aspx
I personally experienced the necessity to use trace flat -t272 on such an environment (AlwaysOn) resulting with gaps in the IDs. Sometimes the business logic can be related to the Identity keys.

So the question becomes really debate-like. 
However, it DEPENDS!